# SOAP Literal WSDL request JDEdwards

Tags: php, soap, jdedwards

I recived following wsdl (pasting only part of it for clarity) from my client, after he upgraded JDEdwards ERP system in his company.

```
<message name="createSalesOrder2C">
    <part name="createSalesOrder2C" element="tns:createSalesOrder2C"/>
</message>
<message name="createSalesOrder2CResponse">
    <part name="createSalesOrder2CResponse" element="tns:createSalesOrder2CResponse"/>
</message>
<message name="BusinessServiceException">
    <part name="fault" element="tns:BusinessServiceException"/>
</message>
<portType name="CreateSalesOrderManager">
    <operation name="createSalesOrder2C">
        <input wsam:Action="http://oracle.e1.bssv.JP5F0013/CreateSalesOrderManager/createSalesOrder2CRequest" message="tns:createSalesOrder2C"/>
        <output wsam:Action="http://oracle.e1.bssv.JP5F0013/CreateSalesOrderManager/createSalesOrder2CResponse" message="tns:createSalesOrder2CResponse"/>
        <fault message="tns:BusinessServiceException" name="BusinessServiceException" wsam:Action="http://oracle.e1.bssv.JP5F0013/CreateSalesOrderManager/createSalesOrder2C/Fault/BusinessServiceException"/>
    </operation>
</portType>
<binding name="CreateSalesOrderManagerPortBinding" type="tns:CreateSalesOrderManager">
    <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#bssvpolicy"/>
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
    <operation name="createSalesOrder2C">
        <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </output>
        <fault name="BusinessServiceException">
            <soap:fault name="BusinessServiceException" use="literal"/>
        </fault>
    </operation>
</binding>
<service name="CreateSalesOrderManagerService">
    <port name="CreateSalesOrderManagerPort" binding="tns:CreateSalesOrderManagerPortBinding">
        <soap:address location="https://domain_removed/CreateSalesOrderManager"/>
    </port>
</service>
```

It's part of Oracle JDEdwards ERP endpoint.
My problem is, that after update, definitions went missing and I only have "Literal" things. Tried few approaches, and ended with:

```
try{
    $soap = new WSSoapClient2($wsdl,[
        'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        'stream_context' => $context,
        'trace' => true,
        'style' => SOAP_DOCUMENT,
        'use' => SOAP_LITERAL,
        'location' => 'https://xxx/CreateSalesOrderManager',
    ]);
    $request = array(
        'AddressNumber' => 1,
        'ShipToNumber' => 1,
        'Reference1' => 'ORDER1234',
        'RequestedDate' => '2018-03-26T09:00:00',
        'Items' => array(
            array(
                'Quantity' => 5,
                'UnitOfMeasure' => 'SZ', // SZ - sztuka - Case Sentitive    
                'ItemNumber' => '0705',
            ),


            array(
                'Quantity' => 14,
                'UnitOfMeasure' => 'SZ', // SZ - sztuka - Case Sentitive
                'ItemNumber' => '0715',
            ),


            array(
                'Quantity' => 17,
                'UnitOfMeasure' => 'SZ', // SZ - sztuka - Case Sentitive
                'ItemNumber' => '0750',
            )


        ),

    );
    $response = $soap->createSalesOrder2C($request);

} catch (SoapFault $e){ }
```

And that gives me **Reqest** result like

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:createSalesOrder2C/>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

No idea, why it's empty. WSDL I had in version before JD Upgrade had all definitions and request I provided created proper soap body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few tries in free time I managed to solve this issue.

JDEdwars got upgraded to another "standard" (WS Standard). and has types defined in different files (which I did not notice)

```
<types>
    <xsd:schema>
        <xsd:import 
            namespace="http://oracle.e1.bssv.JP5F0013/"
            schemaLocation="https://domain.x/CreateSalesOrderManager?xsd=1"
        />
    </xsd:schema>
</types>
```

And problem got solved by changing case sensitivity. For example `AddressNumber` became `addressNumber` and  it **DOES** matter in this case.